# Apply inner join on two tables constructed with minus

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two versions of the same table and want to find the differences between both: which rows have changed? I use a minus query twice to print the changed rows as they appear in the old and new table.

Now I want to add a new query: one that shows me the rows that have changed on a specific column.

```
(select * from NewTable minus select * from OldTable) NewRows
inner join
(select * from OldTable minus select * from NewTable) OldRows
on NewRows.column1 = OldRows.column1
and NewRows.column2 <> OldRows.column2
```

where column1 is the unique row id and column 2 is the changed property.

When I execute **Oracle SQL Developer** I get error **ORA-00933 "SQL command not properly ended"**, and he indicates the definition of NewRows as error. I have also tried with ") as NewRows" but it did not work.

The following query does work, so the NewTable and OldTable are compatible.

```
(select * from NewTable minus select * from OldTable) 
union
(select * from OldTable minus select * from NewTable)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with additional `select * from` on the beginning:

```
select * from
  (select * from NewTable minus select * from OldTable) NewRows
inner join
  (select * from OldTable minus select * from NewTable) OldRows
on (NewRows.column1 = OldRows.column1 and NewRows.column2 <> OldRows.column2)
```

Also be aware of `nulls` your condition for difference `<>` will not cover situation where one value `is null` and second `is not null`. You should probably use:

```
on (nvl(NewRows.column1, 'UNIQUEVAL1') = nvl(OldRows.column1, 'UNIQUEVAL1')  
  and nvl(NewRows.column2, 'UNIQUEVAL2')  <> nvl(OldRows.column2, 'UNIQUEVAL2') )
```